# get HTTP code in json response in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I need to save the response code that was sent via json, for example 404:

```
Route::fallback(function(){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found'], 404);
})->name('api.fallback.404');
```

I tried with this code:

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as Resp;

if (!$this->response_code) {
     $this->response_code = Resp::getStatusCode();
}
```

but laravel return me this error:

> Non-static method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::getStatusCode() should not be called statically

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a non-static method (meaning, a method belonging to the object) from the Class itself. Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as Resp;

if (!$this->response_code) {
  $this->response_code = $this->getStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: error 500: AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Montross50\\DatabaseLogger\\Monolog\\Handler\\DatabaseHandler::getStatusCode()

Comment: I assumed that this in your context referred to the request. Guess it's not the case. Please add a little more context so we can help better

Answer (score 0):

Jaime's answer looks pretty good as a general solution to any error where they say it cannot be called statically, but I'm not seeing that method on the `Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse` object at all--hence the 500 error you reported back.

The Laravel documentation for `JsonResponse` indicates that you can call [status()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html#method_status) on the `JsonResponse` object to get the int value of the response code.

Comment: I tied with `res::status()` but return error: Non-static method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::status() should not be called statically

Comment: It’s not a static method either. Can you update your question with some more context with the source code? Maybe clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [http_response_code()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) to get the response code.

```
$this->response_code = http_response_code;
```